# How to check if checkbox is checked when submiting a form in Thymeleaf and Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-validator

I want to check if the checkbox is checked when submitting a form.

I need to validate the user input at server side so I am using Spring MVC Form validator.

I am checking the form with a UserFormValidator class but I do not find how to validate the field checkbox.

The html code:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/addUser}" th:object="${userForm}">
    <!-- other fields ... -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="isTermsChecked" value="" th:checked="${isChecked}"> 
    <span class="text-danger" th:text="${errorTermsChecked}"></span>
    <button type="submit">Get Started</button>
</form>
```

That's what I did in the Controller class:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/addUser")
public ModelAndView addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, String isTermsChecked) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    boolean isChecked = false;
    System.out.println("isTermsChecked: "+isTermsChecked);
    //check is checkbox checked
    if (isTermsChecked == null) {
        modelAndView.addObject("isChecked", isChecked);
        modelAndView.addObject("errorTermsChecked", "Please accept the Terms of Use.");
    }else{
        isChecked = true;
        modelAndView.addObject("isChecked", isChecked);
        modelAndView.addObject("errorTermsChecked", "");
    }

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors() || isTermsChecked == null) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("view_addUser");
    } else {
        //add user ...
        modelAndView.setViewName("view_addUser");
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

My code seems to work correctly and I do not know if it's the correct way.

Comment: can't you do this on client side. JavaScript / jquey ?

Comment: Hi, @want2learn we can validate the user input at client side using JavaScript but it’s necessary to validate them at server side.

Comment: if that is the case, why don't you add one more field isTermsChecked on your userForm object to validate it.

Comment: @want2learn Hi, I tried to add a field in the UserForm Class and in the html I tried this `<input type="checkbox" name="isTermsChecked" th:field="*{isTermsChecked}">` 
but it did not work for me I got I error in the checkbox input 
but I do not remember this error for that I am trying I other solution. 
and I have not found an example.

Comment: @want2learn I added a field on on the userForm and the validation works but when I use `th:field="*{termsChecked}"` I can not check or uncheck the checkbox input in the view.

Comment: Take a look at these SO post. You will get some Idea.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211085/thymeleaf-checkbox-not-passing-value
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424715/thymeleaf-checkbox-bind-list-of-object

Comment: @want2learn Thank you I appreciate your help.
I'm a bit confused, I'm not using a loop. I have only one simple checkbox. I want the correct syantaxe. that's what I wrote `<input name="checked" th:field="*{checked}" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" th:checked="*{checked}" />` but now I can no longer checked or unchecked the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only removed th:field=*{checked} and everything is working properly and that's what I did:

```
<input name="checked" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" th:checked="*{checked}" />
```

and in the controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/contact")
public String contactUsHome(@Valid @ModelAttribute("mailForm") final MailForm mailForm, BindingResult bindingResult)
        throws MessagingException {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return HOME_VIEW;
    } else {
        emailService.sendSimpleMail(mailForm);
        return REDIRECT_HOME_VIEW;
    }
}
```

and for the validation I used Spring Validation:

```
public class MailValidator implements Validator {
    //...
    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        //...
        MailForm mailForm = (MailForm) obj;  
        validateChecked(errors, mailForm);
        //...
    } 
    private void validateChecked(Errors errors, MailForm mailForm) {
        if (mailForm.isChecked() == false) {
            errors.rejectValue("checked", "mailForm.checked");
        }
    }
}
```